# CMake doesn't recompile source file when it's changed?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm using cmake to build my library, when i change one of LIB_SRCS files and type make in command line it doesn't rcompile that file!

```
set (LIB_SRCS
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/A.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/B.cpp
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/C.cpp
)
add_library (mylib SHARED ${LIB_SRCS})
add_dependencies(mylib ${LIB_SRCS})
```

Comment: Please note that the last line - `add_dependencies` - is not necessary as it is implied by the call to `add_library`.

Comment: What generator are you using?  Makefiles?

Comment: I knew that add_dependencies is not necessary, but I put it just to make sure. I am using makefile

Comment: If this CMakeLists.txt file is in the same directory that the "src" directory is, then you can just use "src/A.cpp", etc. without the prefix.

Comment: Any part of this involve network filesystems?  Any misconfigurations on your system(s) related to time?  Any extra copies of those files floating around?

Comment: None of this is happening, peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the first thing you should check is modification time of .o and .so vs .cpp
When mtime of .cpp is greater than .o then it should rebuild. You can test it even without modification by 'touch' file.cpp.

In some strange scenario time can be mismatched due to many reasons and then it will not work.
Possible reason can be for example some demon which plays with system time, or using network file system, and others.

However in real life scenario it is usually not make mistake but developer mistake :-)

Comment: you are right, the editor has time conflict and modify files with old date and time, I tried another one and it worked!thanks